# How to hide or show the widget by setting time

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, widget, show-hide

[This](http://www.urstrulyvijay.blogspot.com) is my blog and i have implemented 2 widgets which i have included in the below code snippet. My aim is to achieve like the below image. i mean just like blink but not exactly blink but show/hide particular widget for some days like 2 days or for 1 week. I mean the 2 widgets should be replaced by time .

[image]

I mean if 1st widget is shown for some time and 2nd widget should be hided and if the 2nd widget is shown the first widget should be hide i mean is there any way to set time for hiding or showing the widget.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdn.rawgit.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.css" />

    <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
   
 <script src="//cdn.rawgit.com/indrimuska/jquery-editable-select/master/dist/jquery-editable-select.min.js"></script>


            <div id="multi-search">
              <select id="cmbColumn" name="cmbColumn">
                <option value="" />Columns
                <option value="apple+" />apple
                <option value="grapes+" />grapes
              </select>
              <select id="cmbSidebar" name="cmbSidebar">
                <option value="" />Sidebars
                <option value="mango+" />mango
                <option value="berry+" />berry

              </select>




<script>
$('#cmbColumn').editableSelect();
$('#cmbSidebar').editableSelect();
</script>
              
              
              <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.4/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/chosen.jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<div>
  <em>Multiple Select with Groups</em><br>
  <select data-placeholder="Your Favorite Football Team" style="width:350px;" class="chosen-select" multiple tabindex="6">
    <option value=""></option>
    <optgroup label="NFC EAST">
      <option>Dallas Cowboys</option>
      <option>New York Giants</option>
      <option>Philadelphia Eagles</option>
      <option>Washington Redskins</option>
    </optgroup>
    <script>
$(".chosen-select").chosen();
      
</script>
```

Comment: I'm confused by the question, what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @godmode ok if first widget is shown and it should be automatically replaced by second widget for some days i want to show/ hide did u understand just like blink but not for some time i want to replace 2 widgets by 1 week or 2 days or 1 day like that

Comment: you can add a jquery hanlder for 'show' to both controls and call hide using window.setTImeout

Comment: You're not going to achieve this by just using Javascript as Javascript is run in the User Browser and you cannot be assured that the user won't refresh the page before it's 2 days, 1 week or whatever your time interval. Who would keep 1 page open looking at it just like that for that amount of time anyway. Can you perhaps be a little bit more realistic in the time interval? Maybe 1 minute? If that were the case you can use window.setTimeout as per @Wolfgang suggested. Otherwise you might have to utilize a database in some way.

Comment: didn't recognise your timespans are that long.. the only way to do this in scrips is to use the Date() object and hide/show controls onLoad based on rules defined on Date, e.g. show 1st control on even days

Comment: @Morgs  can you provide any working example.....

Comment: @Wolfgang I'am requesting you to provide working example

Comment: Added a simple example as fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uunzq61e/ In this example I don't care about exact timespans, just checking for the day onload, but you should get an idea how to do this. Let me know if this is what you were looking for and I will add it as an answer

Comment: @Wolfgang Yeah i have seen ur fiddle when  i will see green color i mean in which part of the code should i change i mean after how many minutes or days......?

Comment: @Wolfgang this code if (now.getDay() % 3 == 0)   will get automatically change according to date ......? i mean like 1 after 2 after 3rd day or should i modify every time when i want to show the code on that day.....?

Comment: new Date() retuns a DateTime object.
So today you see the red one, tomorrow you'll see the green one. I use the getDay() method which returns an int 0..6 for Sun..Sat.

Comment: @Wolfgang  thats ok but should i edit every time if (now.getDay() % 3 == 0) this code or it will automatically renders according to date daily i mean after 24 hours it will change to other day i think you got my question right

Comment: in this example, the variable "now" is always set to the DateTime when the scripts gets executed. So you do not have to change it. With every page load "now" will get the current DateTime and based on this you can hide/show your controls. But if you keep your page open for some days.. this will not change automatically as the current script is only called onload

Comment: @Wolfgang as the above widgets are used to keep on webpage to show user to appear different view ok thanks but can u apply the code for above 2 widget I'am editing 2 widget let me edit just 4min

Comment: if you cahnge the condition to.. if (now.getMinutes() % 2 == 0) and refresh the page, you can see that it will load based on the current minute

Comment: @Wolfgang can u make the changes to the above code snippet which you have done in the fiddle if you wont mind....

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/uunzq61e/1/ but I still don't really know what you want.. show the controls for some days and then the other for some days or dynamicall switch controls during a user is at your page, or give the user some time to edit your controls or switch, ..?

Comment: your first fiddle works https://jsfiddle.net/uunzq61e/ but this wont worked https://jsfiddle.net/uunzq61e/1/ it is not hiding not to take my controls or switch i want to display the <div id="multi-search"> for some time and at that time <div id="multi-search-groups"> should be hided same thing if this <div id="multi-search-groups"> is shown then <div id="multi-search"> should be hided i think you got me right

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118938/discussion-between-wolfgang-and-overflowstack9).

Comment: it solved thanks for helping @Wolfgang

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found an answer to this (together with "overflowstack9"):

The differnet controls are shown using the Date() object for validating show/hide onload. 
Be sure that this is only an example and read the comments to make sure you understand why we didn't use events or timeouts here:

```
var control1VisibleCheck = function () {
  var now = new Date();
  //TODO: modify this logic to your needs: have a look on the Date() object's members and methods to implement what you need
  if (now.getMinutes() % 2 == 0)    //I'd like to show control1 on even minutes
    return true;
  return false;
}

if (control1VisibleCheck())
  document.getElementById('multi-search-groups').style.display = 'none';
else
  document.getElementById('multi-search').style.display = 'none';
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/uunzq61e/2/